# Can I use PCSC(APDU) for communication between an android phone and a nfc card reader(Identive 4700f) via android beam?

Tags: nfc, apdu, nfc-p2p, pcsc, android-beam

I am completely new to the NFC scene and pardon me if this question is quite obvious. I have an Identive Cloud 4700f card reader and I want to use my android phone to beam data to this card reader via android beam.I do not intend to use HCE since I want a to&fro(P2P) communication.Is this possible through the PCSC protocol using c-APDU and r-APDU. If so is there any knowledge base where I can get a list of all APDUs to communicate to&fro (P2P) between the card reader and the phone.
Here is the [link](http://www.epsys.no/images/identive/pdf/CLOUD47x0F_UM_EN_V1.0_00001763015.pdf) to Identive 4700f Data sheet

Comment: @ the person who down-voted the question can you please explain which part about this question is off topic?

Comment: I guess you cannot "send" data from your phone to the card reader. You can request data from your phone by the card reader itself. At least as far as I know PC/SC is restricted to this type of architecture (non-p2p). Also the card reader you provided uses default CCID protocol which is designed to answer to host requests and is not able to initiate commands by itself (except asynchronous events ` `RDR_to_PC_NotifySlotChange` and `RDR_to_PC_HardwareError`)

Comment: any update on this?